# findOneAndUpdate() does not update values

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am implementing a function using node.js to update a value in mongoDB. Below is my mongoDB collection,

[image]

I want to update the values of the `totalRating` and `totalVotes` inside the `ratings` array. Therefore, I implemented the function as below in node.js.

```
router.post('/addReview', (req, res) => {

   Product.findOneAndUpdate(
       {_id: req.body.productId},
       {
           "$set" : {
                    "ratings.totalRating": req.body.rating,
                    "ratings.totalVotes" : req.body.votes
           }
       },
       {new : true},
       (err, productInfo) => {
           if(err) return res.json({success:false, err});
           res.status(200).json(productInfo)
       }
   )
});
```

Below is the `Product` Schema,

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const AddItemsSchema = new Schema({
    _id: {type:String, required:true},
    img: {type:String, required: true},
    category: {type:String, required: true},
    name: {type:String, required: true},
    description: {type:String, required: true},
    price: {type:String, required: true},
    quantity: {type:String, required: true},
    size: {type:String, required: true},
    meterial: {type:String, required: true},
    discount:{type:Number, default: 0},
    comment:{type:Array, default: []},
    ratings:{type:Array, required: true}
});

const Products = mongoose.model('additems', AddItemsSchema);

module.exports = Products;
```

When I sent a post request using postman, it does not update the db values and it returns null. Can someone please point me out where I am doing wrong? Thanks!

Postman request body,

```
{
    "productId": "5eb82cd3e8b80155fc3ee021",
    "rating" : 4.0,
    "votes" : 1
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are couple of issues in your code :

1) First & major issue is not with update part but with filter part of query :

```
.findOneAndUpdate(filterPart, updatePart)
```

> So from basic functionality of [.findOneAndUpdate()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findOneAndUpdate/index.html) - It will
>   return `null` if it doesn't find any document with input filter. If it finds a document & not able to update it for any reason then it would either returns an error or old document (If no issue with query syntax and no update is performed).
>
> **Also just as a note :** When option `{ upsert : true }` is used
>   without `{ new : true }` & if there is no matching doc - then
>   result will still be `null` though it creates a new document. It's
>   because as originally `findOneAndUpdate` didn't find any document.

So your issue is with input `req.body.productId` which is of type `string` but your `_id` in database is of type `ObjectId()`, You need to convert it prior to querying DB like this :

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

router.post("/addReview", (req, res) => {
  Product.findOneAndUpdate(
    { _id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.body.productId) },
    {
      $set: {
        "ratings.0.totalRating": req.body.rating,
        "ratings.0.totalVotes": req.body.votes,
      },
    },
    { new: true },
    (err, productInfo) => {
      if (err) return res.json({ success: false, err });
      res.status(200).json(productInfo);
    }
  );
});
```

2) There is an issue with update part as well :

As `ratings` is an array of objects `[{},{}]`, you can not do like below :

```
{
    "$set" : {
              "ratings.totalRating": req.body.rating,
              "ratings.totalVotes" : req.body.votes
      }
}
```

cause in `$set` operator `ratings.totalRating` & `ratings.totalVotes` is trying to set/create fields `totalRating` & `totalVotes` under `ratings` - if it's an object then it would work. Since it's not - then you need to say to which object in array you should be doing this update operation as like below :

```
{
  $set: {
    "ratings.0.totalRating": req.body.rating,
    "ratings.0.totalVotes": req.body.votes,
  },
}
```

From above we're updating first object in `ratings` array. In general if there'll always be only **one object** then make `ratings` as an **object** rather than array, else if it will have **multiple objects** then keep it as an **array** & add a unique value to each object. Which helps to identify which particular object needs to be updated while [positional](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/index.html) operators are being used on updates.

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide the indexing to update array

```
   router.post('/addReview', (req, res) => {

   Product.findOneAndUpdate(
       {_id: req.body.productId},
       {
           "$set" : {
                    "ratings.0.totalRating": req.body.rating,
                    "ratings.0.totalVotes" : req.body.votes
           }
       },
       {new : true},
       (err, productInfo) => {
           if(err) return res.json({success:false, err});
           res.status(200).json(productInfo)
       }
   )
});
```

Comment: Still the same issue. BTW thanx for helping

Comment: @MarketMAD I have updated the answer, if changing schema doesn't work, keep the schema as it is and use the array index in the query